# Zizaco/Entrust middleware HttpException

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Zizaco.Entrust ACL in one of my project, But i am getting HttpException while applying Zizaco Entrust middleware on route. It look like i have missed something.

Here in my route and kernal .php files.

```
Kernel.php

....

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
        'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
        'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,

    ];

....

route.php

.....

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('login/','UserController@loginForm');
    Route::post('login/','UserController@login');
    Route::get('logout/','UserController@logout');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','role:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('register/','UserController@register');
    Route::post('register/','UserController@store');
    Route::get('home/',['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']); 
});

....
```

I did not understand i have follow almost tutorial available on github and still i am getting this error.

I have searched on internet related to this issue, but i did not found any solution.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What specific HttpException error are you getting?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: I have switch to Laravel default ACL. I will try to use. Once i resolved i will let you know.